# Replacing whole word in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I want to find and replace whole word in SQL Server e.g. If i am finding the word "day" and i want to replace the word "day" with empty space. But while searching the word "day" other words should be part of results set for e.g. "Holiday".

I have got solution in below link. But i am unable to use this in replace statement

http://blog.conceptinfoway.net/databases-database-server-web-database-online-database-database-hosting-database-developer-database-management-database-development/how-to-amatch-whole-word-in-sql/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want only ram and not programme then you may use this

```
create table temp(nnn varchar(max))
insert into temp values('programme'),('is ram home')
select * from temp where nnn like '% ram %'
update temp
set nnn='x' where nnn like '% ram[ .,'']%'
select * from temp
drop table temp
```

this only alters the second item and not the first one.

Comment: an anonymous user claims 'this will not work if your string is "ram's horn", for example'

Comment: @JanDvorak hope it is fine now. that was probably my first answer when I had just started to learn. Sorry for that.